# How does one achieve realtime messaging between different instances of (perhaps different) PHP scripts?

Tags: php

I'm working on feeding the client realtime events using event-streams and HTML5 SSEs client-side.

But some of my events will actually come from form submissions by other clients.

What's the best method for detecting these form submissions (so as to append them to the event-stream script) ASAP (after they occur)?

So essentially, I need realtime cross-script messaging between multiple instances of different scripts instantiated by different clients, analagous to X-doc messaging in JS, but for PHP.

The best I can come up with is to repeatedly poll a subdir of `/tmp` for notification files, which is a terrible solution.

Comment: [Realtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing) is not what you think about here. You are just looking for cross-process-communication which is possible in [PHP with ZMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:php).

Answer (score 0):

Often you can use MYSQL to play the role of the tmp dir you were talking about.  This is more portable because they don't have to be on the same server to do this and the data is separate.  However the scripts will have to manually check the mysql location to see if the other one has taken care of this.  The other option is to open sockets and write back and forth in real time or to use some prebuilt tool for just this purpose which I'm pretty sure might exist.

Comment: Could yoou give me some examples of how to use sockets?/ Thanks :P

Answer (score 0):

If you want the events to be triggered near to realtime, then you need to handle them synchronously - which means running a daemon. And the simplest way to implement a daemon which can synchronize data across client connections is to use an event based server. There's a nice implementation of the latter [using php here](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5758-PHP-Handle-requests-to-network-servers.html) - there are plenty of examples of how to daemonize a PHP process on the interent. Then just open a blocking connection to the server from your PHP code / access this via comet.